# Need to change Selectedindex of dropdownlist when I click the checkbox in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to create a dynamic page with dropdown list and checkbox, this part is completed.
Second part is that the selected dropdown list should go to default value(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)  when I click the checkbox.
I tried but no luck. Can anyone suggest ideas?

```js
var AnswerView = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {defaultselected: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"};
   },
    render: function() {
    //Picklist -1 
    //Text      -2
    //Date      -3
     return (<div>
    <tr><td><select value={this.props.responses.length==1?this.props.responses[0].lw_questionanswerid.Id:""}><div>
    <FormatePickList answers={this.props.answers} defaultselected ={this.state.defaultselected}/>   
    </div></select></td></tr><br></br><br></br>
    <tr><td>
          No Answer<input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.responses.length==1?this.props.responses[0].LW_UnabletoobtainData:false} 
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'question')}/>
          Not Applicable<input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.responses.length==1?this.props.responses[0].LW_NotApplicable:false}/>
        </td> 
       </tr>
     </div>);
    }
  ,handleChange: function(field, e) {
   this.replaceState({defaultselected: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"});
   this.setState(e.target.checked)
   }
});
    var FormatePickList=React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    var rows = [];
    rows.push(<OptionValues key={-1+"-v"} value={this.props.defaultselected} text={""}/>);   
        for(var i = 0; i < this.props.answers.length; i++) 
        {
           rows.push(<OptionValues key={i+"-v"} value={this.props.answers[i].LW_questionanswerId} text={this.props.answers[i].LW_answer}/>);   
        }
      return (<b>{rows}</b>);
   }
});    

var OptionValues=React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return(<option value={this.props.value}>{this.props.text}</option>);
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do at the line `this.setState(e.target.checked)`? I don't think `setState` accepts this value, you should pass an object. Besides, you're already replacing the state with `replaceState` in the line above.

Comment: Please ignore these lines

Comment: Please ignore those line's in handleChange event.Please tell me which code need to write to reset the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what `this.props.answers` and `this.props.responses` are, I have difficulties reproducing your problem. However, it's clear to me that you want some checkbox to automatically change the value of a dropdown to the 'default' or 'no answer' value.

You'll need to handle the onChange event for both the checkbox and the select-element. In the event handler you'll update the state to whatever answer is selected, so, in the case of the select-element it's the selected answer and in case of the checkbox it's always the 'no answer' value.

An example of how you're able to do this:

(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thijs_s/r00haqjt/1/)

```js
var AnswerView = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            'selectedAnswer': 'no_answer'
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div>
            <select onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.selectedAnswer}>
                <option value='no_answer'>No answer</option>
                <option value='answer1'>Answer 1</option>
                <option value='answer2'>Answer 2</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <input onChange={this.handleNoAnswer} type='checkbox' value='no_answer' checked={this.state.selectedAnswer=='no_answer'} /> No Answer
            <p>Current state: {this.state.selectedAnswer}</p>
        </div>
        );
    },
    handleChange: function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.setState({
            selectedAnswer: e.target.value
        });
    },
    handleNoAnswer: function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.checked);
        if(e.target.checked) {
            this.setState({
                selectedAnswer: 'no_answer'
            });
        }
    }
});

React.render(<AnswerView />, document.body);
```

Keeping in mind that you have to stay away from 'anti-patterns' (http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html), you can define the initial state through the properties. From your comments I understand that if there's a response (checking the length of the array) then the first answer should be selected (the `[0]` in your code). So what you basically want, is to have your initial state set to this first answer. The logic (code) for this, can be put outside of your React class and the initial state can passed to it through a property. I updated the JSFiddle to show how it's done: http://jsfiddle.net/thijs_s/r00haqjt/2/

Comment: Thanks..your code is working fine..
I have to use same variable in value in select-element and onChange event also.
how can maintain the same variable in both places?

Comment: Because these values are getting from ajax call.
<select value={this.props.responses.length==1?this.props.responses[0].lw_questionanswerid.Id:""}>

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. I've extended my answer with an explanation on how to set the initial state based on your AJAX input. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.